# Associate .mm files with Freeplane

Tags: mime-type, file-association

I use [Freeplane mind-mapping software](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It creates .mm files which Nautilus reports as `Troff MM input document`. I want to be able to open a file with Freeplane by double-clicking it in Nautilus.

I have a `.desktop` file for Freeplane with the mime-type set as `application/x-freemind`.

I added a mime-type for `*.mm` files as `application/x-freemind` but this didn't change anything.

Right-click **Open with…** still doesn't show Freeplane.

Freeplane is installed in a folder under home simply by unzipping an archive and adding a `.desktop` file under `~/.local/share/applications` pointing to the `freeplane.sh` script file.

How do I associate .mm files to Freeplane.

I'm using Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way would be to open the terminal and go to a folder where a **mm** file is. Then do the following:

`mimeopen -d FILE.mm`

A small terminal based menu will appear asking you, to which program you wish to associate the **mm** extension. If none in the list are freeplane, then simply select option **5**. Then type the executable for freeplane, which I will assume it is `freeplane`. This will make freeplane open the file used. Now close and open any Nautilus window (You may need to actually logout and login again) you have opened and you are done. Next time you right click a **mm** file, freeplane will appear in **Open With**.

UPDATE: Ok installed freeplane and did the step mentioned above (I was right to guess the executable was `freeplane`) and this is what I came out with:

[image]

It appears in the image above as the first option becase I had already done it althought I did not check if it was there in the first place.

[image]

Just to make sure, do a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall freeplane`. Just tested in 12.10 and 13.04. If it still does not work, can you provide any additional information that can help me narrow down the cause?

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to install freeplane.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found that the problem was with the .desktop file. Instead of `%f` at the end of the exec line there was a `%U`. Change done, Freeplane appeared amongst the possible applications.

Comment: @ToDo - No problem buddy. Glad I helped somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/180627:

1. Install Freeplane with the Ubuntu Software Center, or type `sudo apt-get install freeplane` in a shell.
2. Install the program File Types Editor (also known as AssoGiate) from the Ubuntu Software Center, or type `sudo apt-get install assogiate` in a shell.
3. Open this Editor (type `assogiate` in a shell) and click on the "New" button to add a new type.  Enter in the following information:

   - General tab:

     - category: Multipurpose files
     - name: freeplane
     - description: mindmapping
     - default icon: (browse to select your Freeplane icon -- look in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/`)
   - Related Types tab:

     - add an alias to `application/x-freeplane`
   - Filenames tab:

     - add the `*.mm` pattern
4. Click OK to complete the addition of the new type, and close assogiate.

Now you should be able to open .mm files from Nautilus using Freeplane.